# How can I make a JPanel appear when I click a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I have a ColorChooser panel, how can I make that appear when I click a JButton in my program?
EDIT:
I want to make it appear in a new frame that is resizable, movable and closable.

Comment: Need more info. Appear from where? The same window from behind another panel? Popup in a dialog?

Comment: I want to make it appear in a new frame that is resizable, movable and closable.

Comment: how did you get the ColorChooser to appear?  do the same as that with your own panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an ActionListener for your JButton.

Something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author roger
 */
public class MyActListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public MyActListener(){
        super("My Action Listener");

        JButton myButton = new JButton("DisplayAnything");
        myButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(myButton);


        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MyActListener ma = new MyActListener();
    }

    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { // YOur code for your button here
    if("DisplayAnything".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
        Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Color Chooser", Color.BLACK);
        JButton displayAnything = (JButton)e.getSource();
        displayAnything.setBackground(c);
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) of [How to write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). Look at the really big index in there to see basic tutorials about java in general.

Comment: Can I please get feedback from further readers if this is the right way to write an action listener for a JButton? when the number of buttons start to grow, is it better to make a class for it that implements ActionListener? or instead of `myButton.addActionListener(this);` make `myButton.addActionListener(new MouseListener(){...})`

Comment: I personally prefer using anonymous inner classes like the last example in your comment and make calls to classes that implement the logic from there. This way, there is no need to define action commands and as you noticed, your actionPerformed method will get rather long when new buttons are added. All of your examples are valid and in use of course.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question, how can I make the button appear the color I choose?

Comment: @LucPeetersen As I said before the edit, put your code on the actionPerformed method; you can do whatever you want in there. I'm afraid that was not your original question though.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the Java Swing Tutorial - ColorChooserDemo2:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#advancedexample

Basically, JColorChoose can be shown in a dialog:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html

```
Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(
                 ColorChooserDemo2.this,
                 "Choose Background Color",
                 banner.getBackground());
```

For the button to activate this file chooser:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
    //color is whatever the user choose  
        Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(currentComponent, "Color Chooser", Color.WHITE);  

        JButton thisBtn = (JButton)e.getSource(); //or you can just use button if that's final or global
        thisBtn.setBackground(color);
    }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks :)
How can I implemented that in my ActionPerformed from my JButton?

Comment: Ok thanks, just one more question, how can I make the button appear the color I choose?